# Android Studio Gradle Sync add arguments

Tags: android, gradle

I am trying to pass SVN revision number to our gradle based build machine. It is fine if I use variables like $svnRevision in build.gradle. and run command like "gradlew.bat build -PsvnRevision="1234".

But Android Studio cannot sync and run the build script, Is there a way to set customized arguments for Android Studio Sync Gradle?

Comment: look into the `ext { }` block, maybe this http://www.gradle.org/docs/current/dsl/org.gradle.api.plugins.ExtraPropertiesExtension.html

Comment: @Blundell ext is the first thing I tried, sorry I should mention it in the question, ext.variable still needs explicit define, right?

Comment: yeah it does, do you just need the svn var on a CI box and you just need ASide to run? Could always null safe check it and return a default for IDE (which we do)

Comment: You could externalize the property in a *gradle.properties* file. That would still be applied even when using Android Studio.

Comment: @Blundell Yes, we want the CI box to run and the AS ide to build, I will try your idea. Thanks for the help :)

Comment: @MarkVieira thanks for remind me we always can read a .properties file wiht almost anything in gradle :). I saved my keystore properties on CI box and I will try the same way with other needed veriables.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can set default svnRevision in `/<project_root>/gradle.properties`.

```
svnRevision=123
```

Get the parameter in gradle. So gradle task will get this variable when you run `sync`.

```
project["svnRevision"]
```

And you can override this property when you run the gradle command as below.

```
gradlew -PsvnRevision=456 build
```